# Web player not playing files with non-ASCII characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jwplayer

Our app allows users to upload video.

I noticed, as soon as someone uploads a video with "é" in the file name, the video doesn't play.

For example "fooébar.flv". Question is. Should I be saving file names with those characters or should I filter out those chars? Otherwise, should I find a way for my player to play file names with non-ASCII characters?

I am using [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/), to play the media on our site by the way.

**EDIT**

I followed http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16002/embedding-with-international-characters which seems to work with:

```
encodeURIComponent(encodeURI("path_to_file"))
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using ?

Comment: What happens if you log on to the server and try to play one of those files locally ?  Also, can you post the code where you're constructing the url for JWPlayer to play ?  HTML source if possible too.

Comment: @RussC see my edit above. The file plays on the local server. Sorry can't post the URL, since this is a commercial product

Comment: You don't need to post the url; but can you post the HTML generated by your app when JWPlayer is linked to a file with a non-ascii character ?  You'll probably see the error yourself, I suspect Ruby isn't encoding the filename correctly so instead of href=fooébar.flv you get href=fooAEbar.flv or something.

Comment: @RussC `http://foobar.com/uploads/users/1/songs/1/fooébar.flv`

Comment: If you correct that link for your domain, does it work if you put it into the address bar of your browser ?

Comment: Yes, it works in the browser with non-ASCII code as well. The link in my edit allows me to play non-ASCII file names. The question now is, should I allow users to save files with non-ASCII characters in the file name or should I do some kind of filtering?

Comment: I would let them save with non-ascii characters, you don't want to make it harder for your users to upload.

Comment: @RussC Thanks, just my thoughts exactly. If you put your last comment as an answer, I can consider it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ops request in the comments:

I would let them save with non-ascii characters, you don't want to make it harder for your users to upload.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it this way:

```
file_path = <%= "http://localhost/#{CGI.escape( URI.escape( 'File name with extra charaters like & áéű' ) )}" %>
```